# JPanel filled with Buttons inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm currently trying to fill a JPanel (using GridLayout) with Buttons. These Buttons should be squares having a set width.
The programm should be able to resize the playing field (n*m buttons). Problem is, the buttons are automatically stretched to completely fill the JScrollpane, completely ignoring the set height and width. Thus making the scrollbars unnecessary.
Here is my code:

Creating the panels:

```
panel_game = new javax.swing.JPanel();
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(panel_game);
```

Trying to resize the JPanel: (where x and y are the number of buttons and zoomlvl the size)

```
panel_game.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(x, y));
panel_game.setBounds(panel_game.getX()+5,panel_game.getY()+5,x*zoomlvl-5,y*zoomlvl);
panel_game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x*zoomlvl,y*zoomlvl));
```

And adding the buttons: (f is my playfield, a 2D-Array)(buttons is a Arraylist, containing my buttons)

```
for(int i=0; i<f.getSize()[0]*f.getSize()[1];i++){
    buttons.add(new JButton());
    buttons.get(i).setSize(zoomlvl, zoomlvl);
    buttons.get(i).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(zoomlvl,zoomlvl));
    panel_game.add(buttons.get(i));
}
```

I have no clue how I can tell Java to stop resizing my buttons etc. automatically.
Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that we can compile and run unaltered, that shows us your layout, but one that has no code relevant to your problem. In other words, don't give your buttons any ActionListeners, don't use any image files or any non-Java files whatsoever. Please read the link for the details of what we will want to see.

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout is built to fill the container that uses it with components. If the container holding the buttons is constrained in size, then the buttons will stretch or fill to fill that container as closely as possible. A solution may be to nest layout managers so that this does not occur, but I can't give more specific advice without more code, particularly a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Images might help too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the "button grid panel" from stretching to fill the whole viewport area of the ScrollPane, you could place this grid panel into another panel (with `FlowLayout`).

In general, you should either

- not set the preferred size of the `panel_game` **OR**
- not set the preferred size of the buttons

because

- when you set the preferred size of the buttons, then the preferred size of the panel will be computed from the preferred sizes of the buttons
- when you set the preferred size of the panel, then the size of the buttons will be determined by the size of the panel, respectively

Maybe this is what you want to achieve:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ScrollButtonGrid
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        int x = 5;
        int y = 5;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(x, y));
        for(int i=0; i<x*y;i++){
            JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
            panel.add(button);
        }
        JPanel container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0,0));
        container.add(panel);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(container);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```